# How to decrease XP you get for an achievement in Google Play Games?

Tags: achievements, google-play-games

I was playing this game and, when I got to the tenth level in the game (no major feat at all, probably worth only a couple hundred xp), the game gave me 10,000 XP. I feel like taking the full 10,000 XP would make me a cheater at the Google Play levels, so is there a way I could reduce the amount of XP I got for that achievement?

Comment: Pretty sure the XP amount is tied to the achievement.  I don't think you can alter that in any way.

Comment: Could I just undo the achievement?

Comment: Don't think there's a way to alter it - also why does it matter?

Comment: I feel like getting that achievement was a cheat because it gave so much XP for something very inconsequential. I just don't want to feel like I got to where I am by cheating, which this achievement would make me do.

Comment: 1) You're not actually cheating, you can see where the XP came from. 2) Why does it matter what your Google Play level is? It's not like people are looking for level boosters for your google account.. 3) Game makers usually make the achievements, it's not a big deal

Comment: I'm aware that its not actually cheating, but it still feels like it is, and that's my problem. It feels like I'm cheating with that achievement, regardless of if it is or isn't.

Comment: Google isn't going to come down on you and ban you for getting an achievement in a game on their platform. You're overly worried about something that honestly doesn't matter in the long run. And lets be honest here I am sure every gamer on the planet has at least one game that gave them lots of achievements for no effort.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove or change how much is awarded for an achievement or unlocking it in the first place. The values/number of achievements/unlocking events are set by the developer. Once you get it, its yours, adding whatever value to your overall score (and increasing your level if you've passed the needed threshold).

If you don't want to "artificially inflate" your GPG score, you can always either a) not sign into Google Play for that particular game, or b) play things without achievements. You can always check to see what achievements a game has and their value (unless they're secret ones, then you can see they're there but you get less info about them) through the Google Play Games app.

Comment: The problem is, my score is already artificially inflated, and I want it to not be that. It's too late because I started playing the game without thinking that I should check for such achievements. I've stopped playing that game, but that doesn't stop the 10,000 XP it already gave me.

Comment: Well, there isn't anything you can do after the fact. Like I said, it's not removable or able to be changed.